# font-awesome icon displays briefly before changing to a circle with exclamation point

Tags: css, font-awesome-5

Using Font Awesome v5.10.0, I'm attempting to display a standard facebook "f" logo, which according to [Font Awesome's documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/) is invoked with

```
fa fa-facebook
```

and used like

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

The f logo appears momentarily before changing to a round circle with an exclamation point.

What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=facebook&m=free). It will give you the documentation for the Facebook icons. I don't think what you are looking at is correct. Also make sure you have font awesome installed either through the source code or the cdn.

Comment: The link takes me to a landing/marketing page for FA 6.  I do not see any instructions for Facebook icons.

Comment: Try this: go to https://www.fontawesome.com and click on icons. In the search bar type in 'Facebook' and it should come up with all the related icons. Click on which icon you want and then click on 'start using this icon' and it should give you the HTML code for that particular icon.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of Font Awesome, v6 (which you might be already using when including your files), you will not encounter this behavior, because they updated the class for their icons and they now use `fab` instead of `fa`:

```
<i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
```

This should solve it for you!

Comment: I'm on 5.  A twitter icon on the same page displays normally with `<i class="fa fa-retweet"></i>`

Comment: I was apparently using a buggy cdn version.  Obtained fresh CDN link from font-awesome, and the f icon displays properly now.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question since the other two proved not to solve the issue.

I was apparently using a beta/buggy cdn for v5:

```
https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0-12/js/all.js
```

Obtained fresh v5 CDN link from [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/customizing-wordpress/snippets/setup-cdn-webfont), and the f icon displays properly now.